# Swiper js - React (WebComponent) nested swipers with virtual slides not working

Tags: reactjs, web-component, swiper.js

Im trying to use swiper.js with react (webComponent) with nested swipers and virtual slides, but can't get this to work :/

You can check the attached codesandbox, if you comment `virtual={true}` on both `<Swiper>` tags this is working great but without virtual slides and as Im working with lot of slides this can 't be an option.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nest-swiper-virtual-slides-q59yq6?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A26%2C31

`"swiper": "^10.0.4"`

Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks.